# How to delete large volume of data from SQL Server based on multiple condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, sql-delete

I am looking for a SQL query where I have to delete data from a table based on combination of 2 condition.

I have a table `dbo.ABC` from which I have to delete the rows if combination of values pass as input present in column A and column B.

Table - ABC

```
column A   column B
===========================
100           US
200           IND
```

Now I have to delete record if column A is 100 and column B is US. But I want to pass multiple inputs like 100 and 200 as column A and US and IND as column B respectively. 100 and US will be the one combination to delete 1st record and 200 and IND will be the another combination to delete 2 record. Similarly I want to pass 1000 input like this way to delete 1000 records in single shot rather than calling it 1000 times with single input.

Can I use multiple IN statement to delete the data as I have multiple combination of `column_A` and `column_B`?

How to use for-loop to delete the data if I pass many combination of `column_A` and `column_B`?

I am new to this field so not have much knowledge.

Your help will be appreciated..

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your question by adding some sample input and output data.

Comment: You can go with adding all the combination of records in a Staging like Physical Table and JOIN the table with you actual table and DELETE the matching records

Comment: And,  Don't delete huge records in a single process. Go with Nibbling Delete instead. (i.e: Perform a loop and DELETE 10000 records at a time,.... (It's based on your concurrent workload)

Comment: @SQLServerBuddy: since SQL Server will do a **lock escalation** and goes from row-level locks to an exclusive table-wide lock when you try to delete **more than 5000 rows** in a single transaction, I'd suggest making your batches smaller than 5000 rows at once, to avoid locking the whole table exclusively for an extended period of time ....

Comment: @marc_s Yeah! The batch of records may vary one environment to another based on the concurrent process and How the lock manager behaves.

Comment: @SQLServerBuddy: as far as I know, the 5000 rows per transaction limit for lock escalation is system-wide, and doesn't depend on anything, and cannot be influenced ...

Comment: @marc_s, Actually, I never came across such a situation when more than 5000 so for. But, the batch count varied environment to environment in my case (As I mentioned earlier - based on concurrent other operations). Let me leave it to you as per your experience.

Comment: Can you please show your entire table definition? I'm looking for primary keys and indexes specifically.  Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2):

Please note: **I have not debugged this.** But I have used similar stuff for large-scale purge operations on a busy transactional database.

Create yourself a temporary table and populate it with the combinations you want to delete. For example,

```sql
CREATE TABLE #to_delete ( cola INT NOT NULL, colb NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL);
GO
INSERT INTO #to_delete (cola, colb) VALUES
(100, N'US'),
(200, N'CN'),
(300, N'UK');
GO
```

Then do this to test your row-selection logic. This should only return the rows you want to delete.

```sql
SELECT TOP(500) ABC.*
  FROM ABC
  JOIN #to_delete d ON ABC.col1 = d.col1 AND ABC.col2 = d.col2;
```

Once you're satisfied this gets only the doomed rows, then do a so-called nibbling delete.  Repeat the delete query in a loop until it doesn't delete anything. Like this.

```
DECLARE @count INT = 1;
WHILE @count > 0 BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
      SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW;
      DELETE TOP(500) ABC
        FROM ABC
        JOIN #to_delete d ON ABC.col1 = d.col1 AND ABC.col2 = d.col2;
      SET @count = @@ROWCOUNT;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END;
```

Why is this a good way to go?

1. It deletes a small chunk of rows with each query, minimizing both the lock time for rows in the table and the size of each delete transaction.
2. The low deadlock priority is just insurance. If one of these DELETE operations deadlocks with some other query, possibly on some index, we definitely want to kill the DELETE operation, not the other query. We can just repeat the DELETE query.
3. The short delay between chunks allows your transactional workload to get time to run.